# Show error message from trigger in lightning

Tags: trigger, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have a trigger written on Account to throw error. It is working fine when processed from detail page of a record, but I have made a aura component in that component how should I show the error from Trigger.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Share your component controller code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that you are processing records in a component using `@AuraEnabled` methods in Apex to update the Account record in some way, any errors that occur in a trigger on the account will need to be handled and passed back to the Lightning component so that the error is displayed to the user in a readable way.

[Examples of this can be found here in the Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html)

The basics of this are to Use a `Try/Catch` block within your code to catch any errors that occur and then pass out your desired message as a `AuraHandledException`, the above link also shows more detail around how this message can be handled on the client side to display in a readable manner.

Comment: Hi , I want to show the error message in lighting while using the standard feature no aura component code. Ex- We have a trigger which use the adderror message in contentdocumentlink and now when we try to add a document from the lightning UI , it shows the error message as 'cant add file 1 to case' rather than the custom message which is their in the trigger. Is their any way to get similar msg as trigger add error message

Answer (score 0):

Apex code

```
try{
    //backend logic. Tigger adds error message
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

Lightning Code

```
action.setCallback(this,function(data){
    if(state === 'ERROR'){
        var errors = data.getError();
        //parse the error string using regular expression 
        //or using substring whatever suits
        //var errorMessage = helper.getErrorMessage(errors);
        //show modal(or whatever) with the parsed message
    }
}
```

You can parse in the catch block(apex) as well. 
I prefer javascript because its easy and helper code then can be later saved as a .js resource file and shared across various components.

Comment: what are you doing in helper.getErrorMessage(errors); ?

Comment: @Nielsm in the helper method, i do three things-- 1)parse the stack trace and take substring, 2)showing a toast, 3) logging that error(inserting) in my logger object(custom object)

Comment: could you add an example?